# QGraphics scence

Tags: c++, graphics, qt4

I have trouble using the QgraphicsScene in Qt.

When I am initializing the QGraphicsScene in the main.cpp i am able to use that. But when I am try to add that to an Widget & then add that to the main window its not working, I am not able to view anything. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the QGraphicsScene in a QGraphicsView. Then put the QGraphicsView in your widget.

Comment: yes  I am doing that...i have used the QGraphicsView inside one widget & calling that widget in the main class. BUt not comming.

Comment: well then it is somewhere in your code. Keep looking or if you can isolate your problem and paste it here may be someone will be able to help you. BTW this smells like your QGraphicsScene object is dead, make sure you're not creating your scene is some function/constructor.